# Executing scripts in background permanently on webserver

Tags: php, node.js, api, server

To extend the request limits I want to fetch data from an API endpoint and provide them to my users from a third party hosting platform. They usually support php so I was thinking of using it. The data should update like once a minute or every two minutes. The fetching process itself could be as simple as possible, e.g. like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('abc.com/xyz');
file_put_contents('example.json', $json);
```

Like this an endpoint would be fetched and written into a local file. But to repeat this step continuously and keep the data updated this script would be needed to run permanently or executed frequently. The only way I found was to use cron jobs for that issue but would that be recommendable to use to keep files updated? Or are there way better methods to do this?

I know that there are better setups to solve that issue like handling it with node.js but I consider using a platform like this so I only have to manage the communication between the API and the server and not between server and clients and didn’t find another way to do so but I‘m open to other suggestions!

Comment: Looks like you've found the answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the question was more aimed on if it‘s recommendable to use cron jobs or if that‘s something that should be avoided for such a case at all costs

Comment: Nope. Learn to use and love them.

Comment: Okay great, thanks @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can be done differently (like with node.js you mentioned or other methods), I believe that a system cron job to be run every X minutes (depending on how long it takes for the API to respond) will suffice and keep things simple.

Provided of course that you are able to set-up system cron jobs on your webserver.

Comment: What would happen if it takes longer for one cron job and overlaps with a new started cron job, would they conflict each other or would they still work and be executed and the data would just be delayed once?

Comment: That depends on the script you utilize for the API call, if it only consists of the above two lines then overlapping  cronjobs will cause two processes trying to write on the same file (example.json) which will mess up your data.

Comment: If you need to sync the data from API as soon as possible (like every minute for example), you should create a more complex script that will check for the existence of a lock on the operation and only if the lock is not in place proceed to create the lock, perform the sync and lastly remove the lock.

Comment: The lock, can be a file for simplicity (example sync.lock), a value in your database or even a value in a in-memory storage like Redis (if you have one running on your webserver)

Comment: Ah okay, so a simple check like `if(file_exists(xyz))` would be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, this can suffice - remember to:

1. check for the existence of lock file
2. if it exists stop execution
3. if it does not exist create it
4. proceed with the sync process
5. delete the lock file once you are done

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, the comments do not allow lists.

Comment: No problem at all, thank you very much for your help! :)